# Standardinstallation show web servive instead of webinterface

Tags: solr, ckan

Following this receipt http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html I have installed a #ckan on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.
On the machine was still a solr installation.
After all I see

`{
      help": "\n        Get help at:\n        http://ckan-service-provider.readthedocs.org/."
}`

instead a colored web GUI.

During the install of solr solr was without password and the script `sudo ckan db create` successful. After adding of basic Authorization I have added the creds to ckan.conf.

Any ideas/hints?

Comment: Here the production.conf (symlink to developement.conf): https://gist.github.com/AppWerft/e4070552156335045cc2a78973a208dd

Comment: You're talking to the ckan-service-provider/datapusher service, not the main ckan one. I believe there should be two apache configs - one for each. And somehow the wrong one is connected to port 80. It probably sets up nginx in the middle, so check the config of that too. Do paste apache and nginx configs here if you need more help.